# Create a class with a dictionary/multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

So I'm fairly new to Python, with a little bit prior knowledge of programing.

I've just gone through classes but haven't found much on how to use a class with a dict. So thought if someone could help explain this, it might help others as well.

What I'm doing right now is that I have multiple dictionaries, using the `defaultdict()` import, I want to create a class to use these. Let me give you an example, following are my dictionaries and some constants:

```
DEFAULT_MAX = -99
DEFAULT_MIN = 999
DEFAULT_STR = 'DATE'

max_temperature = defaultdict(lambda:DEFAULT_MAX)
max_temp_date = defaultdict(lambda:DEFAULT_MAX)
min_temperature = defaultdict(lambda:DEFAULT_MIN)
max_humidity= defaultdict(lambda:DEFAULT_MAX)
min_humidity= defaultdict(lambda:DEFAULT_MIN)
```

I will also be needing some methods whereby my functions would take data from variables. Another example:

```
if max_temp > max_temperature[year]:
    max_temperature[year] = max_temp
    max_temp_date[year] = date
```

Where `max_temp` amd `date` are set to the default constants above and are compared by a loop and replaced by the maximum value.

I think using a class to make instances(or something, naive beginner) would be a good idea for this.
Even if it isn't I'd really like to learn how to use classes to do this.

Really hoping to learn. I've heard there are some nice people here :)

Comment: you probably should ask this kind of questions on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov there is no such example on this whole site, if you read my question properly, I thought it could help others with a similar problem and I used this code to serve as an example.
Also I didn't know about codereview so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using classes, try the following:

```
class weather_year:

    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year
        self.max_temp          = -99
        self.min_temp          = 999
        self.max_temp_date     = 'Date'
        self.max_humidity      = -99
        self.min_humidity      = 999


    def add_weather(self, date, 
                          min_temp = 999, 
                          max_temp = -99,
                          min_hum, = 999 
                          max_hum  = -99):
        if self.max_temp < max_temp:
            self.max_temp = max_temp
            self.date = date
        self.min_temp = min(min_temp, self.min_temp)
        self.min_hum =  min(min_hum, self.min_humidity)
        self.max_hum =  max(max_hum, self.max_humidity)
```

note that the class weather_year has a method add_weather that lets you add all your readings. to use:

```
thisyear = weather_year(2018)
thisyear.add_weather('2018-10-10', min_temp = 42, max_temp=76, min_hum = 75, max_hum = 99)

print(thisyear.date)
2018-10-10
print(thisyear.min_temp)
42
```

Comment: Hey Marc, sorry for the late review and thank you for the prompt response. You haven't mentioned anything about the dictionaries in the class. I wanted all 5 of my dictionaries, that you can see in the code, to be initialized and processed in the class. Or is that an incorrect assessment?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to achieve here. my assumption is that you need some sort of code that will let you deal with various temperature and other weather readings during a certain period (such as a year). Dict for you is just a convenient vehicle to do this. Is this correct?

Comment: The thing is that as soon as you want to throw methods or functions into the mix in order to apply some sort of logic to a new entry, dicts aren't that usefull and it is better to go with a class (IMO anyway).

Comment: Got it, it helps anyways. Thanks again.